# React state is not being updated by my call to the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, jsx

I'm new to React but looking at similar questions and answers, I think this should be working. but it's just returning null. if I set the default state to an empty array it sill just returns and empty array. also i'm getting no errors and the fetch IS being called.

```
import React, { Component } from     "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import BreweriesContainer from "./BreweriesContainer";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https:api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_state=Colorado")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonData => {
        this.setState({ names: jsonData.name });
        console.log(this.state.names);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <p>{this.state.names}</p>
    <BreweriesContainer />
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: first off, you got missing double-slash within URL (`fetch` parameter)

Comment: `setState` is async, try to log it at the setState callback: `this.setState({ names: jsonData.name}, () => console.log(this.state.names));`

Comment: Make sure you are getting response from your fetch. Console your `jsonData` not your `this.state.names`. Also like @YevgenGorbunkov said you may have made a typo in your URL.

Comment: It's returning the data if i console.log(jsonData). just not updating the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jsonData.name` will not work because the request is return an array with multiple values with a key called `name`. So `jsonData.name` will be undefined. Try `jsonData[0].name`.

If you want all the names use a map function like this:

```
this.setState({ names: e.map( (object) => object.name ) });
```

Also, you should do the console log like @Kishan said:

```
this.setState({ names: jsonData.name },() =>{
        console.log(this.state.names);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 this.setState({ names: jsonData.name },() =>{
        console.log(this.state.names);
});
```

console in setstate callback you will get updated state or console in render function

Comment: If you console.log() what jsonData is before the setState() call is there something there? Also note how here, the console.log() is not -after- the setState call but the second argument to it, you've written it like that right? I say that because if setState() works, then the console.log() should too, think that's been tested to exhaustion now.

Answer (score 0):

console.log immediately after a setState call, won't work as expected because setState updates the state asynchronously and the console.log statement won't wait for the setState to finish before printing out the previous/default value

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just a typo?

this.setState({ names: jsonData.name });

should perhaps be

this.setState({ names: jsonData.names });

Comment: It's not a typo, the object returned on the 'https:api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_state=Colorado' has a key called name so it should be ```jsonData.name```

Comment: No, the JSON data is an array, no an object with a "name" property.

Comment: Yes, you're right sorry, an array of objects with a key ```name```

Comment: I probably should change the name of my state. it's a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

Diogo has your answer, `jsonData` is an array so you need to access it with `jsonData[0]`